# Extract values using multiple variables in JSON Extract JMETER

Tags: json, foreach, jmeter

I m new to jmeter tools . Here i have extract data from Json Extractor using multiple variable names which i want to use the variable again in for each controller to call the data based on the variables used .

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note that you are expected to have researched your issue and made attempts to solve it before posting. If you have a specific question, it should include details of what you have tried so far and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

1. Given the following JSON Response

   ```
   {
     "employees": [
       {
         "firstName": "John",
         "lastName": "Doe"
       },
       {
         "firstName": "Anna",
         "lastName": "Smith"
       },
       {
         "firstName": "Peter",
         "lastName": "Jones"
       }
     ]
   }
   ```
2. And the next [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) configuration

   [image: JSON Extractor Configuration]
3. JMeter will produce the following variables:

   [image: JMeter JSON Extractor multiple variables]
4. The relevant [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) configuration which will iterate all `firstName_xxx` variables will look like:

   [image: JMeter ForEach Controller]

Demo:

[image: JMeter ForEach Controller Demo]

I would also recommend checking out [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor) article for more comprehensive explanation of JSON Extractor usage.